# Is it safe to pass a _bstr_t object to a function expecting BSTR as argument?

Tags: c++, msdn, bstr

I am new to C++ so please bear with me. I know that `_bstr_t` is just a wrapper class for `BSTR` but, as seen in the MSDN documentation, `_bstr_t` does not have an operator to convert itself to `BSTR`.

So can I pass a `_bstr_t` object to a function expecting a `BSTR` as argument, and is it safe?

Or is there any better way to do this? I especially don't want any memory leaks with this.

I have seen numerous articles so just got confused about this. Sorry if it is a trivial question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *`_bstr_t` does not have an operator to convert itself to `BSTR`*

Yes and no. `BSTR` is defined to be equivalent to `wchar_t*` in the "afx.h" header file:

```cpp
typedef _Null_terminated_ LPWSTR BSTR;
```

And the `_bstr_t` class (in "comutil.h")  *does* have conversion operators for that, with or without a `const` qualifier, as in:

```cpp
class _bstr_t {
public:
//...
//...
    // Extractors
    //
    operator const wchar_t*() const throw();
    operator wchar_t*() const throw();
//...
```

---

EDIT: But one minor 'note of caution' from the [documentation for those operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/bstr-t-wchar-t-star-bstr-t-char-star?view=msvc-160):

> Assigning a new value to the returned pointer does not modify the
> original BSTR data.

Comment: So would it be safe for me to pass the _bstr_t object as parameter and not worry about any leaks or issues??

Comment: @RajaShekar Yes! If the function parameter should be a `BSTR` then the conversion will be done; and I would like to think the *implementations* of the two operators whose *declarations* I have shown would be 'safe'.